# Vertex Degree Proof

Tags: graph-theory

The degree of every vertex of a graph $G$ of order $2n+1\geq5$ is either $n+1$ or $n+2$. Prove that $G$ contains at least $n+1$ vertices of degree $n+2$ or at least $n+2$ vertices of degree $n+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume otherwise. Then we need *exactly* $n$ vertices of degree $n+2$ and $n+1$ vertices of degree $n+1$ to have a total of $2n+1$ vertices. If $e$ is the number of edges, this means that $$2e= n(n+2)+(n+1)(n+1) = 2n^2+4n+1$$
so even=odd, contradiction. ($2n+1\ge 5$ was not used in this proof).

Answer (score 0):

**I misread the problem, so this won't work.**

Suppose both statements are false, so we know that the number of vertices with degree $n+1$ is at most $n$ and the number of vertices with degree $n+2$ is at most $n$. Since every vertex has degree $n+1$ or $n+2$, we now know that the total number of vertices is at most $2n$. Since the number of vertices $2n+1$, we have a contradiction. Thus, one of the original statements must have been true.

This is essentially the [pigeon principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) with $2n+1$ objects divided over $2$ boxes.

Comment: You are off by one